# How do you use Maven-Publish Android Gradle Plugin's generated components in Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.kts)?

Tags: java, android, maven, kotlin, gradle

Currently I'm working with an old Kotlin DSL build script that publishes an Android AAR library to a Maven repository. The dependencies are added to the pom-default.xml via simplistic iteration through the implementation configurations. Similar to this:

```
    withXml {
       val dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")
       configurations.getByName("implementation") {
         dependencies.forEach {
            val dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode("dependency")
            dependencyNode.appendNode("groupId", it.group)
            dependencyNode.appendNode("artifactId", it.name)
            dependencyNode.appendNode("version", it.version)
         }
       }     
    }
```

This doesn't translate the exclusion statements, and so now publishes useless broken libraries with conflicting classes. I'd like to be able to use the Android Gradle Plugin's generated build artifact components instead, because I understand that by using these, the pom file will be automatically generated with the right list of dependencies (presumably with the exclusion clauses).

The documentation to do this is given here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin

Unfortunately, as always, the example given is Groovy, and I cannot find any example of the syntax you would use in a Kotlin Gradle script.

```
from(components["release"])
```

...didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, turns out...

```
from(components["release"])
```

...does work, I just didn't put in the...

```
afterEvaluate {
```

...clause, recklessly assuming this was just a Groovy thing.

Remember kids, stay away from drugs, work hard at school and follow the documentation faithfully, to a tee.